# Get lm estimate for each categorical variable

Tags: r, regression, lm

So I am doing a multiple linear regression to see if fracture density and rock type effect retreat rates in rocks.

```
retreat <- lm(retreat_rate ~ fracture_dens + rock_unit, data = coast)
> summary(retreat)
```

I would like it to treat the 'rock_unit' as a category.  I have two rock types in the vector.  Here is my current result.

```
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          -0.22631    0.53806  -0.421 0.676353    
fracture_dens         0.11467    0.02704   4.241 0.000132 ***
rock_unitSC_mudstone  1.73490    0.36097   4.806  2.3e-05 ***
```

I would like there to be 'SC_mudstone' and 'Purisima' (the other rock type) instead of the 'rock_unitSC_mudstone' it is giving me now.

Comment: You can go trough [this tutorial](http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/interactions_and_contrasts.html) to understand how `lm` works (it's about interactions and contrasts, but helped me to understand estimates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the typical outcome for linear models: the variable `rock_unitSC_mudstone`is  a dummy variable which is defined as:

rock_unitSC_mudstone = 1 if rock unit = SC_mudstone and 0 otherwise.

Adding a further variable `rock_unitPurisima` would cause the model matrix $X$ to not have full rank.

Anyway, you do not need the `rock_unitPurisima` variable. You can interpret the results as follows:

Average retreat rate for SC_mudstone  = -0.22631 + 1.73490
Average retreat rate for Purisima = -0.22631

If you insist on a variable `rock_unitPurisima`you can set the intercept to zero:

```
retreat2 <- lm(retreat_rate ~ 0 + fracture_dens + rock_unit, data = coast)
```

But as I said, an intercept and both dummy variables would simply contain too much information.

Hope that this was helpful.

Comment: Nice answer, but what do you by "would simply contain too much information"? Because if final summary you're just replacing `Intercept` with `rock_X`.

Comment: So the intercept gives you the average (retreat rates) for all categories, while dummy variables give you an additional average rate which has to be added to the intercept.
In your case you want to know the average for both classes (SC, and Pur). 
There are two ways to give you that information. Either directly (i.e. no intercept) or indirectly (intercept and average for one class). But giving an intercept and both averages would be too much information (i.e. more than you need).

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. The numbers were correlating with the data, just didn't want to interpret it incorrectly.